# Problema com return false em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso desenvolver um menu acordeon e estou tendo problemas com o evento de clique. Meu script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown').click(
        function(){
            $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

O SlideToggle chama uma lista não ordenada que fica dentro de um elemento LI. Funciona perfeitamente, mas os links da lista param de redirecionar. Quando clico em algum deles, o slideToggle() simplesmente se desfaz, o menu retorna ao estado original e não sou redirecionado. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Poderia incluir um demo da estrutura do menu? Acredito que possa ser problema com relação a propagação do evento de `click`.

Comment: Insira isso como parte do HTML da sua pergunta

Comment: @PedroVinícius, poderia incluir também o elemento com classe `dropdown`? Acho que ajuda a descobrir o problema :)

Comment: @Wakim, o código do menu é gerado automaticamente pelo WP. Mas se você puder dar uma olhada no código-fonte no site, segue o link:

http://conscienciaestelar.filosofiaesoterica.com.br

É o menu da esquerda que está com esse problema :/

Comment: @PedroVinícius, ok, irei dar uma olhada

Answer (score 2):

O erro ocorre justamente pelo `return false;`, que não deixa que o evento iniciado no link do submenu termine de executar.

Inclua o seguinte código logo após o registro do `handler` para o `click` no dropdown:

```
$('.sub-menu a').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Ao dar `stopPropagation` no clique do link, você irá previnir que o evento propague para cima, e ai não bloqueará o evento de navegação.

E ao clicar sobre o link, o usuário será redirecionado para a página.

Answer (score 1):

Em [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) existe uma função chamada `.preventDefault()` que "nega" o evento original de uma *tag* HTML, desta forma você pode usa-lo para que seus links não tenham seu efeito original assim que forem clicados

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown').click(
        function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder amigo. Mas já tentei com essa função também. O efeito é o mesmo :-/

Answer (score 0):

Vamos imaginar que seu HTML esteja assim:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Abrir drop down A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link A 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link A 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="">Abrir drop down B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link B 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link B 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

E seu script esta aplicando o `click` ao elemento `.dropdown` quando o correto é aplicar o clique ao link filho direto do elemento `.dropdown`.

Então seu `jQuery.click` deve ficar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown >a').click(function(){
       $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle();
       return false;
    });
});
```